# Compare types if one is nullable

Tags: c#, reflection, types, nullable

I need to check if two types are the same:

```
private bool AreOfTheSameType(object obj1, object obj2) {
  return obj1.GetType()==obj2.GetType();
}
```

This works fine with this values:

```
var test1=AreOfTheSameType(new DateTime(), new DateTime()) // true;
var test2=AreOfTheSameType(new int(), new DateTime()) // false;
```

What I now want is that the following returns true, too:

```
var test3=AreOfTheSameType(new int?(), new int())
```

So if the types have the same base, but one is nullable, the other isn't, I also want to return it as true. Or to say it in another way I want to have a function that returns whether I can store obj1 into obj2 directly using reflection without having to cast the value.

**UPDATE**

I reduced my code to make it more readable. Looks like this time that was contra-productive. The real-world-code follows:

```
var entity = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
Type entityType = typeof(T);
PropertyInfo[] entityProperties = entityType.GetProperties();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> fieldValue in item.FieldValues)
{
   if (fieldValue.Value == null) continue;
   var property = entityProperties.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.Name == fieldValue.Key);
   if (property != null && property.CanWrite)
   {
      Type valueType = fieldValue.Value.GetType();
      if (fieldValue.Value.GetType() == property.PropertyType) {
        // Assign
      }
   }
}
```

The problem on the "//Assign" - line is, I have the following two types:

```
fieldValue.Value.GetType().ToString()="System.DateTime"
property.PropertyType.ToString()="System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]"
```

which are obiously not the same but could be assigned

Comment: Btw, where do these variables come from? Are they already cast into `object` before calling the method? If their type is known at compile time, you can use generics, but once you assign a nullable to an `object` variable, the "nullable" part is lost.

Comment: "Looks like this time that was contra-productive." - [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), a common issue on Stackoverflow. :) As @Jamies wrote, `property.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(fieldValue.Value.GetType())` would do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> which are obiously not the same but could be assigned

It looks like you're after the [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var dt = typeof(DateTime);            
var nd = typeof(DateTime?);

Console.WriteLine(dt.IsAssignableFrom(nd)); // false
Console.WriteLine(nd.IsAssignableFrom(dt)); //true
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/KDOW15238

Answer (score 2):

Calling `GetType` on nullable types returns the original type:

```
int? i = 5;  
Type t = i.GetType();  
Console.WriteLine(t.FullName); //"System.Int32"
```

So `AreOfTheSameType((int?)5, 5)` should return `true`.

But as soon as you box a `Nullable<T>`, you either get `null` (if `Nullable<T>.HasValue` was `false`), or you get the boxed underlying value, losing the "nullable" part. So the problem you're facing here is that `new int?` will be boxed into a `null` object when passed to the method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with nullable types is that empty values box to `null`, and once they're `null`, you **cannot** find out what they were. The only way to solve this, then, is with generics:

```
private bool AreOfTheSameType<T1,T2>(T1 obj1, T2 obj2) {
  // get the types as best we can determine
  var t1 = obj1?.GetType() ?? typeof(T1);
  var t2 = obj2?.GetType() ?? typeof(T2);

  // Nullable<T> => T
  t1 = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t1) ?? t1;
  t2 = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t2) ?? t2;

  // compare
  return t1 == t2;
}
```

This will use the object *if available* (to allow for subclasses etc), but will fall back to `typeof` if the object is null - which means it should work for `int?` etc... **as long as** the type of the expression being passed in wasn't `object` to begin with; if it *was* `object` and the value is `null`, then... you're out of luck - you can't ever find out the original type. By which I mean:

This should be fine:

```
var test3=AreOfTheSameType(new int?(), new int());
```

But this will fail:

```
object x = new int?(), y = new int();
var test4=AreOfTheSameType(x, y);
```

Comment: Generics also came to my mind, although I doubted the type would be known at compile time, but +1 for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Groo yeah, it is double-edged; if you can prove to the compiler (via generic type inference) that the types are compatible, then you probably should have already **known** that fact at the call-site without calling the method - the approach does have uses, but: limited

Comment: After the update, turns out the problem was completely different all along. :)